# What do all these types of nihilism mean?

Tags: heidegger, nihilism, deleuze

> [Nihilism](http://www.fourbythreemagazine.com/issue/nihilism-the-play-of-blooming-nihilism-brian-schroeder) manifests itself in various contexts—for example,
>   individual and collective, historical and psychological—and different
>   expressions, for instance, ontological, epistemological, ethical,
>   political, logical, theological. Its types are also variegated:
>
> - incomplete,
> - complete,
> - extreme,
> - consummate,
> - ecstatic.

I've also heard of

- reactive,
- active, and
- passive.

These latter three appear in Deleuze, when he claims that the "higher man" is just a means for reactive men to deify themselves:

> The prophet is a prophet... representative of passive nihilism, prophet of the last man... The ugliest of men
>   represents reactive nihilism: the reactive man has turned his ressentiment against God, he has put himself in the place of the God he has killed (Nietzsche and philosophy p155)

What does each mean?

Comment: i think it's meant to be incomplete / reactive (history of nihilism), complete / passive (despicable men), extreme / active (artists?), consummate (nietzsche), ecstatic (heidegger), but i'm guessing

Comment: Nihilism is a term covering everything from the philosophical rejection of existence to the pervading feeling induced by clinical depression.

Comment: yeah, but i think that's a philosophy blog? haha @Richard

Comment: well, even from a technical philosophy position, Nihilism has multiple exact meanings.. hence the OP's question.

Comment: There is a commonly used logical or (grammatical) opposition active/passive and also a more physical one "active/reactive". Both are indeed in Deleuze writings, not necessarily connected with nihilism. And the rest here is just a bunch of adjectives.

Comment: Isn't this too broad even by your standards? What exactly unites these "nihilisms" aside from a common name? And if we are talking Deleuze and Heidegger, even one of these senses might take a page or two. Is there one sense in particular you interested in and can focus this on?

Comment: are you sure they're just a bunch of adjectives?